# Toggling x-data based on another conditional in alpine js

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I am creating a blade component and I want to toggle the tooltip to only show up on the icon if the left sidebar is closed.

It looks something like this

```
// layouts.app
<div x-data="{leftSidebarOpen:false}">
       // some designs
       <div>
            // adding blade component
            <x-menu-item/>
       </div>

<div>   

// inside blade component
@props=(['title'=>'page title'])
<div x-data="{tooltip: '{!! $title !!}'   }" x-tooltip.placement.right="tooltip">

      //icon
</div>
```

I am still trying to learn javascript so how to write this function in alpine is still a bit confusing. Found this in the docs, that might be helpful for anyone that is more proficient https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data

I pretty much want to make it

```
If leftSidebarOpen === true for the tooltip:'' else if the leftSidebarOpen === false than tooltip='{!! $title !!}'
```

Any insight on how to solve this, or maybe a better way to accomplish the same goal is much apprecaited. Just trying to make the tooltip not show up on the icon if the menu is expanded.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you want to use a [getter](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data#getters) that returns some data based on some conditions where you can also access data defined in `x-data` attributes. In the `x-menu-item` child component we can access both `leftSidebarOpen` and `tooltip` data, so we can define a `getTooltip` getter, that checks the value of `leftSidebarOpen` and returns `tooltip` if it's `false`, and empty string otherwise.

```
<div x-data="{tooltip: '{!! $title !!}',
              get getTooltip() {return leftSidebarOpen ? '' : this.tooltip}}" 
     x-tooltip.placement.right="getTooltip">
  //icon
</div>
```

Note that inside the getter, we have to use `this.tooltip` to access data defined in `x-data`.

Comment: You are incredible! thank you :)